# Change build settings prior to project build

Tags: xcode

I wrote a ruby script that changes some build settings through a .xcconfig file.
*(Don't ask me why, but it improves our workflow quite a bit; different environments etc.)*

And I put it in the first row (after 'Target Dependencies') in my `Build Phases`.
The only problem is when I build my app the variables defined in that xcconfig file are not used for that particular build. But for the build that follows.

The only reasonable explanation would be that the project build parameters are already set when the `Build Phases` start.

So my question is quite simple:
Is it possible to run a script before the project gets build. So I'm talking about pressing `⌘ + R`; first my script runs and then fires up the project build.

Stuff I tried:

- Using 'pre-actions' in build schemes
- Using an 'External Build System' target
- Using an 'Aggregate' target

None of them seem to give me the desired result